# Get minimal logging when loading data into temporary tables

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, import, database-internals

After reading [The Data Loading Performance Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), I am still unsure if it's necessary to add the TABLOCK table hint to an empty temporary table, defined with a clustered index, in order to get minimal logging.

Obviously, the temp table is created in TempDB, which operates in the SIMPLE recovery mode, so I would have thought that it was a perfect candidate for minimal logging; however, I can not find a passage to confirm it.

Is a temporary table a candidate for minimal logging, and if so, is it worth adding the TABLOCK hint as recommended for permanent tables?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> *I am unsure if its necessary to add the `TABLOCK` table hint to an empty temporary table, defined with a clustered index in order to get minimal logging.*

No. Local temporary tables (`#temp`) are *private* to the creating session, so a table lock hint is not required. A table lock hint would be required for a global temporary table (`##temp`) or a regular table (`dbo.temp`) created in `tempdb`, because these can be accessed from multiple sessions.

Note that even where the full minimal logging optimizations are not applied, tables created in `tempdb` benefit from other optimizations like not needing to log `REDO` information. You can test to see whether rows or pages are being logged using the undocumented `sys.fn_dblog`. Regular logging will feature row-logged records like `LOP_INSERT_ROWS`.

---

Note that adding `TABLOCK` to a local temporary table is required to get parallel execution with `INSERT...SELECT` queries in SQL Server 2016, see the Microsoft Knowledge Base article:

[Poor performance when you run INSERT.. SELECT operations in SQL Server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3180087)

Comment: Has this changed over the years? Even in SQL Server 2022, I insert in to all of my just-created local temp tables `WITH (TABLOCK)`. I hope it is still the correct thing to do.

Comment: @J.Mini It hasn't changed, no.