# logical reads on global temp table, but not on session-level temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporary-tables

Consider the following simple MCVE:

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME OFF;
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t1', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t1;
CREATE TABLE #t1
(
    r int NOT NULL
);

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##t1', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##t1;
CREATE TABLE ##t1
(
    r int NOT NULL
);

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.s1', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.s1;
CREATE TABLE dbo.s1 
(
    r int NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

INSERT INTO dbo.s1 (r)
SELECT TOP(10000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM sys.syscolumns sc1
    CROSS JOIN sys.syscolumns sc2;
GO
```

When I run the following inserts, inserting into `#t1` shows no stats I/O for the temp table.  However, inserting into `##t1` *does* show stats I/O for the temp table.

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
GO

INSERT INTO #t1 (r)
SELECT r
FROM dbo.s1;
```

The stats output:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.
Table 's1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 19, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 9 ms.

(10000 rows affected)
```

```
INSERT INTO ##t1 (r)
SELECT r
FROM dbo.s1;
```

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.
Table '##t1'. Scan count 0, logical reads 10016, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 's1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 19, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 47 ms,  elapsed time = 45 ms.

(10000 rows affected)
```

Why are there so many reads on the ##temp table when I'm only inserting into it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Minimal logging is not being used when using `INSERT INTO` and global temp tables**

**Inserting one million rows in a global temp table by using `INSERT INTO`**

```
INSERT INTO ##t1 (r)
SELECT top(1000000) s1.r
FROM dbo.s1
CROSS APPLY  dbo.s1 S2;
```

When running `SELECT * FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)` while the above query is executing,  ~1M rows are returned.

[image]

*One `LOP_INSERT_ROW` operation for each row + other 
log data.*

---

**The same insert on a local temp table**

```
INSERT INTO #t1 (r)
SELECT top(1000000) s1.r
FROM dbo.s1
CROSS APPLY  dbo.s1 S2;
```

Only going up to 700 rows returned by  `SELECT * FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)`

[image]

*Minimal logging*

---

**Inserting one million rows in a global temp table by using `SELECT INTO`**

```
SELECT top(1000000) s1.r
INTO ##t2
FROM dbo.s1
CROSS APPLY  dbo.s1 S2;
```

[image]

**`SELECT INTO` a global temp table with 10k records**

```
SELECT s1.r
INTO ##t2
FROM dbo.s1;
```

**Time and IO Statistics**

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 's1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 19, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 10 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

---

**Based on [this blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-2016-minimal-logging-and-impact-of-the-batchsize-in-bulk-load-operations/) we can add `TABLOCK` to initiate minimal logging on a heap table**

```
INSERT INTO ##t1 WITH(TABLOCK) (r)
SELECT   s1.r
FROM dbo.s1
```

**Low logical reads**

```
Table 's1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 19, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(10000 rows affected)
```

---

**Part of [an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/85892/get-minimal-logging-when-loading-data-into-temporary-tables) by @PaulWhite on how to achieve minimal logging on temporary tables**

> No. Local temporary tables (#temp) are private to the creating
>   session, so a table lock hint is not required. A table lock hint would
>   be required for a global temporary table (##temp) or a regular table
>   (dbo.temp) created in tempdb, because these can be accessed from
>   multiple sessions.

**Creating a regular table to test this:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.bla
(
    r int NOT NULL 
);
```

**Filling it up with 1M records**

```
INSERT INTO bla 
SELECT   top(1000000)s1.r
FROM dbo.s1
CROSS APPLY  dbo.s1 S2;
```

**>1M logical reads on this table**

```
Table 's1'. Scan count 17, logical reads 155, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'bla'. Scan count 0, logical reads 1001607, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

---

**Paul White's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061253/logical-reads-on-empty-target-table-when-inserting-into-it/30656174#30656174) explaining the logical reads reported on the global temp table**

> Generally, logical reads are reported for the target table when the
>   insert is not minimally logged.
>
> These logical reads are associated with finding a place in the
>   existing structure to add the new rows. Minimally-logged inserts use
>   the bulk-loading mechanism, which allocates whole new pages/extents
>   (and so does not need to read the target structure in the same way).

---

**Conclusion**

The conclusion being that the `INSERT INTO` is not able to use minimal logging, resulting in logging every inserted row individually in the log file of tempdb when used in combination with a global temp table / normal table.
Whereas the local temp table/ `SELECT INTO`/ `INSERT INTO ... WITH(TABLOCK)` is able to use minimal logging.